# Variable undefined although correctly assigned I think

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script to get a `PHP session` user id into a javascript file. Yet when I try to simply alert the user id it says `undefined`?

As shown in code I have tried with simple alert to check the data coming back from the script and it is correct.

```
var user_id;

$.get( "/ajax/actions/getUserId.php", function( data ) {

    // alert(data); <-- this works correctly

    var user_id = data;

});

alert(user_id);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The PHP file accessed (getUserId.php) is simply:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION[user_id];
```

Comment: Your alert is running before your ajax call is complete, so user_id isn't defined at the time the alert runs.

Comment: You also have a scope issue with redefining the `user_id` var inside the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
$.get( "/ajax/actions/getUserId.php", function( data ) {    
    var user_id = data;
    alert(user_id);
});
```

Ajax is **asynchronous** by default.

In your snippet the code goes through the following steps:

1. Define variable called `user_id` in the global lexical scope
2. Make `GET` ajax request to `/ajax/actions/getUserId.php`
3. Alert the value of the variable `user_id` which is `undefined` (by default, you haven't set it any value).
4. At given point the ajax request is successfully completed, your callback gets invoked so:

   1. You define new variable called `user_id`, in the lexical scope of your callback

Comment: Thanks, so can I not use the variable user_id outside the ajax call? I was using the alert AFTER the call as I need the variable further down the js file - or in English, can I make the ajax call happen before the file loads?

Comment: I included extra explanation, you can review it.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney you can leave only the second variable declaration - the one in the ajax callback.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous, so the last alert will be executed before the callback function of ajax is called.